# Firebase Dynamic Link Rest API - 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, firebase-dynamic-links

I am transitioning an existing service from using google url shortener api to try and use Firebase Dynamic Links. I have linked a project from the Google Cloud Platform, and setup a "dummy" android app so that I can have the app domain for the dynamic links. I am trying to use the REST API to shorten urls for very long urls that can't be handled by a third party. I have tried sending using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=****");
FirebaseDynamicLinkInfo dynamicLinkRequest = new FirebaseDynamicLinkInfo();
dynamicLinkRequest.setDynamicLinkDomain("zw5yb.app.goo.gl");
dynamicLinkRequest.setLink(assetUrl);
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(mapper.writeValueAsString(dynamicLinkRequest)));
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
```

I am getting a 400 Bad Request when I post the request to the API (on the httpCLient.execute line. I have double checked my api-key. I have also tried using just the longDynamicLink parameter, and it gets the 400 Bad Request Response.

Any ideas of where I could be going wrong?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Google Support on this one, and I wasn't UrlEncoding my querystring parameters on the deep link. After encoding the link, the request was successful. I went back to using passing json that just had a longDynamicLink property (as opposed to the dynamicLinkInfo object in my original post). Here is what it looks like:

```
String myEscapedUrl = "https://zw5yb.app.goo.gl/?link=" + URLEncoder.encode(assetUrl, "UTF-8");
FirebaseDynamicLinkRequest dynamicLinkRequest = new FirebaseDynamicLinkRequest(myEscapedUrl);
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(mapper.writeValueAsString(dynamicLinkRequest)));
// inform the server about the type of the content   
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
```